# Invalid column when using pivot to convert text row data to columns of 1's and 0's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have two tables, one has student id and ethnicity code fields, another table has ethnicity codes and the corresponding ethnicity. I am trying to use pivot to get it so for students that have multiple ethnicities listed, instead of returning multiple rows, I get one row with fields for each ethnicity, and if the student has that ethnicity listed, a 1 in the field, else a 0.

table 1, ethnicities

| PERSON_ID | ETHNICITY_CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 904370520 | 41 |
| 904370520 | 44 |
| 904370520 | 27 |
| 123456789 | 23 |

table 2, mapping ethnicity code to actual ethnicity

| d | ethnicity_code |
| --- | --- |
| Indian Subcontinent | 27 |
| Chinese | 21 |
| Japanese | 22 |
| Korean | 23 |
| White Non-Hispanic | 10 |

etc. more rows to both tables but hopefully its clear whats in each.

I am trying to use the query

```
SELECT
    PERSON_ID,
    [Indian Subcontinent] AS Indian_Subcontinent, 
    [Chinese] AS Chinese, 
    [Japanese] AS Japanese, 
    [Korean] AS Korean, 
    [White Non-Hispanic] AS White_Non_Hispanic, 
    [Laotian] as Laotian,
    [Cambodian] as Cambodian,
    [Vietnamese] as Vietnamese, 
    [Black Non-Hispanic] as Black_Non_Hispanic,
    [Mexican] as Mexican, 
    [Central American] as Central_American,
    [South American] as South_American, 
    [Other Hispanic] as Other_Hispanic, 
    [American Indian, Alaskan] as American_Indian_Alaskan, 
    [Guamanian] as Guamanian, 
    [Hawaiian] as  Hawaiian,
    [Samoan] as Samoan, 
    [Other Pacific Islander] as Other_Pacific_Islander,
    [Filipino] as Filipino,
    [Other Non-White] as Other_Non_White, 
    [Decline to state] as Decline_to_state,
    [No Response] as No_Response
FROM (select PERSON_ID as PERSON_ID, ips.d as Ethnicity from 
SR_ETHNICITIES e inner join (select description as d, convert(tinyint, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), misc_conv_value)) as ethnicity_code from ITEM_PART_VALUES_SR where ITEM_PART_ID = 659) as ips
on e.ETHNICITY_CODE = ips.ethnicity_code) p
PIVOT
(
    COUNT (Ethnicity)
    FOR PERSON_ID IN
    (   [Indian Subcontinent], 
        [Chinese], 
        [Japanese], 
        [Korean], 
        [White Non-Hispanic], 
        [Laotian],
        [Cambodian],
        [Vietnamese], 
        [Black Non-Hispanic],
        [Mexican], 
        [Central American],
        [South American], 
        [Other Hispanic], 
        [American Indian, Alaskan], 
        [Guamanian], 
        [Hawaiian],
        [Samoan], 
        [Other Pacific Islander],
        [Filipino],
        [Other Non-White], 
        [Decline to state],
        [No Response]
    )
) AS pvt
```

But I get an error "Invalid column name 'Person_ID' "
If I remove the person_ID  from the select statement, I get the correct styled output I wanted,

| Indian_Subcontinent | Chinese | Japanese | Korean | White_Non_Hispanic | Laotian | Cambodian | Vietnamese | Black_Non_Hispanic | Mexican | Central_American | South_American | Other_Hispanic | American_Indian_Alaskan | Guamanian | Hawaiian | Samoan | Other_Pacific_Islander |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

But obviously this is useless if there is no person_ID to identify each row.

When I run the select query that I use in the from part of the pivot query, I get

| person_ID | Ethnicity |
| --- | --- |
| 900190436 | White Non-Hispanic |
| 900093012 | Samoan |
| 900183012 | Mexican |
| 900273012 | White Non-Hispanic |
| 900088836 | White Non-Hispanic |

which has a person_ID field

Could someone help me understand what I need to change in my  query so that each person_ID will transform  n rows of data into a single row per person_ID which shows if they are any of the ethnicities?

My desired output looks like this, where each person_ID has a row with all the possible ethnicities, with a 1 in the ethnicity columns that are in the original table for that person_ID. In the example row below it is just for one person_ID, 123456789, and they would have had 2 rows in the original table, one with ethnicity Chinese and one with ethnicity Vietnamese. I want a row for every person_ID, not just one.

| Person_ID | Indian_Subcontinent | Chinese | Japanese | Korean | White_Non_Hispanic | Laotian | Cambodian | Vietnamese |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using `group by` :

```
SELECT 
   personID
   , count(case when ethnicity_code = 27 then 1 else null end) [Indian Subcontinent]
   , count(case when ethnicity_code = 21 then 1 else null end) [Chinese]
, ... -- for rest of ethnicities
FROM
SR_ETHNICITIES e
GROUP BY
   PersonID
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem. I must have been using bad keywords when searching because all my results were giving me pivot examples.